# Transaction not rolling back properly

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

`@Transactional` not rolling back properly when two different `repositories.save()` is being used. One of the `repository1.save()` persists the data through the same transactional method has `repository2.save()` which fails due to constraint exception. Still the first repository record persists in db.

I have tried adding `@EnableTransaction` management to `@SpringBootApplication` and also tried rollback for property of `@Transactional` but no luck.

```java
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserProfileRepository userProfileRepository;

    @Override
    public User findUserByUsername(String username) {
        return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional()
    public User save(UserTO userTO) {
        User user = User.builder().username(userTO.getUsername()).
        password(userTO.getPassword()).build();
        user = userRepository.save(user);
        UserProfile userProfile = UserProfile.builder().firstName(userTO.getFirstName()).
        lastName(userTO.getLastName()).
        dateOfBirth(AppUtil.parseDateString(userTO.getDateOfBirth())).
        gender(Gender.valueOf(userTO.getGender())).build();

        userProfileRepository.save(userProfile);
        return user;
    }

}
```

user should not be saved as `userprofilerepositoy.save(`) is throwing validation failed exception.

The exception trace is as follows :

> exception is
>   org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not
>   commit JPA transaction; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the
>   transaction] with root cause
>        javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.flash.socio.domain.UserProfile] during persist time
>   for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ] List of constraint
>   violations:[
>           ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must not be null', propertyPath=user, rootBeanClass=class
>   com.flash.socio.domain.UserProfile,
>   messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}

Comment: What is the exception? Is it a RuntimeException?

Comment: nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException  : javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException

Comment: @MaciejKowalski I have dited question so as to add exception log .I have added to help any further.

Comment: as mentioned by @MaciejKowalski: ConstraintViolationImpl is a checked exception, not a RuntimeException... you could use ```@Transactional(rollbackFor=ConstraintViolationException.class)```

Comment: @DirkDeyne I have checked the ode and came to find out that repository.save is not raising exception and hence the rollback is not showing expected behaviour.

Comment: Which database are you using? I suspect you are using MySQL with MyISAM tables  which don't support transactions. Switch to InnoDB tables.